# Parse every element in a Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a Dataframe of some 3700 rows. I used if loop and gave my conditions. The code got executed but i'm only getting one element. I want the to check whole Dataframe and print all elements within my conditions.

```
for i in df:
    i=0
        div = "Divergence spotted at "
    
    if (df.High[i] < df.High[i+1]) and (df.RSI[i] > df.RSI[i+1]) :
        
        print(f'{div}{i}')
        
        i=i+1
        break
    if (df.High[i] > df.High[i+1]) and (df.RSI[i] < df.RSI[i+1]) :
        
        print(f'{div}{i}')
        
        i=i+1
        break
    else:
        print("no divergence spotted")
```

[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfK63.png)
My code exited after printing first element. I want it to check the whole Dataframe and print multiple elements that satisfy my condition.

Comment: please provide a small example of your DataFrame and the matching expected output

Comment: You break the loop in each "if", what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `break`, this stops at the first divergence.

You would rather need:

```
out = []
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    div = "Divergence spotted at "
    
    if (df.High[i] < df.High[i+1]) and (df.RSI[i] > df.RSI[i+1]) :
        
        out.append(f'{div}{i}')
    if (df.High[i] > df.High[i+1]) and (df.RSI[i] < df.RSI[i+1]) :
        
        out.append(f'{div}{i}')
    else:
        out.append('')
out.append('')
```

Output: `['Divergence spotted at 0', '', '', '', '', 'Divergence spotted at 4', '']`

But using a loop is inefficient, a vectorial solution would be:

```
m = (np.sign(df['High'].diff(-1).fillna(0))
       .ne(np.sign(df['RSI'].diff(-1).fillna(0)))
     )
df['divergence'] = np.where(m, 'divergence spotted', '')
```

Output:

```
   High  RSI          divergence
0     1    2  divergence spotted
1     2    1                    
2     3    2                    
3     2    1                    
4     3    2  divergence spotted
5     1    3
```